# how to anchor card view without using coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying anchor a card view on the bottom|center of linear layout which under a coordinator layout which has Linear Layout as its parent and Scrollview as it root view but it is anchoring only on the bottom of the linear layout which is under coordinator layout . I figure out the problem is due to the LinearLayout which is the parent of the coordinator layout but how to solve this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.shareooh.shareooh.ScrollingActivityProfile">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >


      <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/profileSignUpHeaderLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/circular_image_profile"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_image"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:text="@string/username"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeName"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBarProfileLevel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/large_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/large_margin"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/profileSignUpHeaderLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1.4"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
                        android:text="4"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/largeTextSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="YOU PAY"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mediumTextSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/extra_large_margin"
                      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/extra_large_margin"
                        android:ems="@integer/max_ems_description"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/smallDescription"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1.4"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
                        android:text="6"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/largeTextSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="YOU SHARE"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/mediumTextSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"

android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/extra_large_margin"

android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/extra_large_margin"
                        android:ems="@integer/max_ems_description"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/smallDescription"/>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_scrolling_profile_signup"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use coordinate layout as top root element instead of scrollview and apply anchor to cardview. and if you have more content use scrollview inside coordinate layout and use linearlayout inside scrollview.

Comment: then the view inside coordinator will not disappear on scrolling

Comment: sorry i dint get you .. post your new design xml so that i can help you

Comment: Thanx Nidhi . I figured it out

Comment: glad it helps ... please upvote the answer if you find it helpful.